# How to add task label to resources AnyGantt

Tags: label, anychart

I'd like to create a Resource Gantt with AnyGantt, currently, when mouse pointer move to the task, it show the resource name and starttime/endtime. I would like to show task name and starttime/endtime.(with following data, I would like to show "task1", not "Equipment#1")
Anyone can help?

Thanks!

[ {"id": 13, "name": "Equipment#1", "periods": [{"id": "task1", "end": 1494099000000, "fill": "green", "start": 1494055800000}]}]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, period's ID is required field and must be unique for gantt chart live edit purposes. You can set any custom field in your raw data like this:

```
var rawdata = [{
    id: 13,
    name: "Equipment#1",
    periods: [
      {
        id: "task1",
        start: Date.UTC(2017, 4, 6),
        end: Date.UTC(2017, 4, 7),
        periodCustomName: "Task 1" //This value will be used in tooltip's title.
      }
    ]
  }];
```

Since the data is ready, you have to set custom title format for timeline's tooltip:

```
//Getting gantt chart's timeline to work with its tooltip.
var timeline = chart.getTimeline();

//Gettnig timeline's tooltip.
var tlTooltip = timeline.tooltip();

//Setting tooltip title format function to access your custom raw data field.
tlTooltip.titleFormat(function() {
  //If period is hovered.
  if (this.period) {
    //Return periodCustomName-field if specified. 
    return this.period.periodCustomName || this.getData('name');
  }
  //Else return name of data item ("Equipment#1")
  return this.getData('name');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer Alex! If there are several periods for one resource, how to show tip for different tooltip for every different task(for one resource at different time, there are different tasks)

Comment: For the custom tooltips, I have another question, if I have several tasks for one resource at different time, how can I show tooltips for every different tasks?

I found currently, if there are several tasks on one resource at different times, the tooltip showed for all tasks have same tooltip, (the tooltip show the start date/end date, but all tasks with same start/end date, it's one of the tasks start/end date). anyway to have every task show correct tooltip with correct start/end date?